# iptables - force all traffic over VPN (and drop all traffic when no VPN connection)

Tags: vpn, iptables, android

Goal:
Ensure all traffic is forced over VPN tunnel from all network interfaces (wlan0,rmnet0,rmnet1), that is all traffic is **dropped** when not connected to VPN. In other words, Internet traffic should not be allowed, and only traffic over the VPN is acceptable.

So far...
Android Device with iptables binary, wlan & 3g connection
VPN gateway @ 10.10.10.10 (not real address).

```
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

Results:

Traffic appears to be blocked - but so too is connection to VPN.

Any ideas? Appreciate this is only mobile data rmnet0 interface and doesn't have WiFi in here yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use conntrack in this scenario but a much simpler set

```
iptables -A INPUT  -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -s 10.10.10.10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10 -j ACCEPT
```

No need for any connection tracking. You also don't need the `DROP` rules at the end, by the way, the `-P ... DROP` takes care of that.

You'll also want to make sure that you use the IP of the VPN server in your config, otherwise, you'll have to whitelist DNS too:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - a quick question though, and kind of the reason i was being led down the conntrack route... Will i be able to get a DHCP IP address on the WLAN interface & IP Address on the 3G connection with this? The reason i ask is i can only bring the IPtables config up on boot, as anything else needs root... so wlan & mobile data etc may be enabled post boot, but i still need the rules to apply.

Comment: Good catch! Yes, you'll have to whitelist dhcp traffic (UDP 67 to server, 68 from server) too.

Comment: No, ip addresses are negotiated over PPP there, I believe. I'm not too familiar with 3g though, so fire up wireshark and make a 3g connection. You'll see what happens :)

Comment: I know this is the accepted answer, but could you post your final string of iptables commands?